# Show that $f(x)=\cos x-\sin x$ is bounded

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

Show that $$f(x)=\cos x-\sin x$$ is bounded.

We know that $$-1\le\cos x\le1\\{-1}\le\sin x\le1,$$ so I tried to subtract these two inequalities, but it seems that it doesn't work as we get: $$0\le\cos x-\sin x\le0$$
I also noticed: $f(x)=\cos x-\sin x\ge\cos x-(-1)=\cos x+2$ and $f(x)=\cos x-\sin x\ge\cos x - 1$.

Comment: $|f(x)| \leq |\cos x|+|\sin x| \leq 1+1=2$.

Comment: On the upper bound side, $\cos x \le 1$ and $\sin x\ge -1$, so $\cos x - \sin x \le 1-(-1) = 2$. Similarly for the lower bound side.

Comment: In general you can't subtract inequalities, because $a\le b$ does not say $-a\le-b$. But note $a\le b$ if and only if $-a\ge-b$. Apply this to the two inequalities in $-1\le\sin(x)\le1$ and you get $-1\le-\sin(x)\le1$; now _add_ the inequality for $\cos$ and you get $-2\le\cos(x)-\sin(x)\le 2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, that is very cool. May I ask you why $a\le b\iff -a\ge-b$? Is this like a famous inequality, because that's the first time I've seen it?

Comment: @Kaloyan $a\leq b \iff 0\leq b-a \iff -b \leq -a.$ But yes it is a famous double-implication. The way I think about it is, "If you multiply (or divide) an inequality by a negative number, then you must reverse the inequality sign for it to be true."

Comment: Just think about it. $2<3$, so multiplying by $-1$ gives $-2<-3$, except of course actually $-2>-3$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Technically, we can substract inequalities.

Comment: @User that's helpful...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I didn't show how to do this in the comment.  I just wanted to note...

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the triangle inequality:

$$\lvert \cos x-\sin x\rvert\leq\lvert \cos x\rvert +\lvert \sin x\rvert\leq 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

In this way you can find "exact bound" (least upper bound)
$$\cos(x)-\sin(x)=a$$
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(x)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin(x)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$a=\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)$$
$$-\sqrt{2} \leq a \leq\sqrt{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

You can write

$$\begin{cases}-1\le\cos x\le1\\{-1}\le\sin x\le1\end{cases}\\
\implies \begin{cases}-1\le\cos x\le1\\{1}\ge-\sin x\ge -1\end{cases}
$$

We see that it is not possible to sum these inequalities directly from side by side.

We can try the following way to subtract the two inequalities.

Let $a≥x≥b \wedge c≥y≥d$, then we have

\begin{align*}&\begin{cases} a≥x≥b\\ c≥y≥d \end{cases}\\
\implies &\max x-\min y ≥x-y≥ \min x-\max y \\
\implies & a-d≥x-y≥b-c \end{align*}

Hence you get,

$$-2\le \cos x-\sin x\le 2$$

However, you can also write

$${1}\ge-\sin x\ge -1\\
\implies
2\ge1+\cos x\ge\cos x-\sin x\ge \cos x-1\ge-2\\
\implies -2\le \cos x-\sin x\le 2$$

But, more rigorous way is:

$$-\sqrt {a^2+b^2}≤a\cos x+b\sin x≤\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$$

Because, $\cos x-\sin x=-2$ and $\cos x-\sin x=2$ is not possible.

Comment: I got downvote, but in this answer I wrote a technically possible way to subtract two inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

**Never subtract two inequalities which are in the same direction**
It some time you get right result and wrong other time. So subtraction of inequalities is a spurious exercise as the subtraction is non-commutative. Instead one can add two inequalities which are in the same direction to get correct statement all the times.
As $-1 \le \sin x \le 1, -1 \le \cos x\le 1$, we can write
$\sin x \le 1$ and $-1\le \cos x$ you can add these two to get
$$\sin x -1 \le 1+\cos x \implies \sin x-\cos x \le 2.....(1)$$
Similarly, we have $\sin x \ge -1 $ and $1 \ge \cos x$ adding these two. we get
$$\sin x+1 \ge \cos x-1 \implies \sin x-\cos x \ge -2.....(2)$$

Comment: "So subtraction of inequalities is a spurious exercise"? Why? We can substract inequalities.

Comment: 7  > 5  , 6 > 3   if you subtract them you get 1>2.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean ..

Comment: @User Subtraction of two inequalities is also spurious because subtraction is non-commutative: (1)-(2) and (2)-(1) will give two contradictory results.

Comment: Subtraction of two inequalities is spurious, if your substraction is incorrect.

Comment: $$7>5>a\\ 6>3>b$$ We have  $$7-b>5-3>a-6\implies 7-b>2>a-6$$ where, $a<5,b<3$. Then, fix $a,b$ as you want.

Comment: By subtraction one would mean$ 7-6>5-3>a-b$ you are not actually them.  All what I say is that  when A>B and C>D then A-C>B-D may or may not be true, it is spurious.   Whereas $7+6>5+3>a+b$ is always correct.

Comment: That is the point, substraction is possible. But your substraction is incorrect. See my answer, please

Comment: In any case I never subtract the I always add them For instance if A>B and C< D. I write A>B and -C>-D and add them to get A-C>B-D.

Comment: You are right. I agree. But, but my point was different